# Sticky service killed and restart scheduled for 1000ms but never restarted

Tags: android, android-service

I have a running, sticky service that sometimes gets killed with a message:

```
2018-11-19 06:54:42.208 1602-3282/? I/ActivityManager: Force stopping com.example.myapp appid=10309 user=0: from pid 16033
2018-11-19 06:54:42.208 1602-3282/? I/ActivityManager: Killing 14900:com.example.myapp/u0a309 (adj 200): stop com.example.myapp
2018-11-19 06:54:42.210 1602-3282/? W/ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service com.example.myapp/.MyService in 1000ms
2018-11-19 06:54:42.217 1602-3282/? I/ActivityManager:   Force stopping service ServiceRecord{ceedda0 u0 com.example.myapp/.MyService}
```

But after 1000ms nothing seems to happen.

Where do I start investigating?

From `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<service
    android:name=".MyService"
    android:enabled="true">
</service>
```

Comment: why is it killed in the first place? It says "crashed service", you got some crash logs? Also what's the receiver about?

Comment: @TimCastelijns added additional logs and removed receiver. There are no errors before the killing/force stopping.

Comment: you are force stopping the app?

Comment: No, Android does.

Comment: force stopping is pretty extreme. It completely disables your app and all its components until the users starts it again manually. It is expected that the service is not restarted in this case

Comment: @TimCastelijns you should post this as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your service accepts `null` intents, and resumes what it was doing on receiving a `null` intent. [See here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service#START_STICKY)

If you have this problem with a Huawei phone, you should know it is a known problem. Android OS of Huawei phones does not automatically restart background services once they have been killed, despite what Google has stated for sticky services. See for example:

[Huawei support center](https://consumer.huawei.com/en/support/content/en-us00428704/)

[Stop your Huawei smartphone from killing background apps](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/stop-huawei-from-closing-apps-when-you-lock-screen/)

[Enable Autostart on Huawei Device for Opentalk](https://opentalk.to/blog/enable-autostart-on-huawei-device-for-opentalk/)